# I need to insert a javascript code "Including the tags" inside my button onclick event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, button, onclick

```
$("#form_threaded_comment_<?php echo $unique_id;?>").submit(function(){
  $('#<?php echo $vars['resultId'] ?>').<?php echo $append_prepend?>('<?php echo $posting_icon?>');

    elgg.action(this.action, {
    data: $(this).serialize(),

    success: function(data){
      $('#form_threaded_comment_<?php echo $unique_id;?>_textarea').val('');
      $('#reply_form_<?php echo $vars['parent_guid']?>').remove();
      $('#<?php echo $vars['resultId'] ?>').<?php echo $append_prepend?>(data.output);
      $('#form_posting').remove();
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

=============================

HTML Code:

```
<button onclick=" ..........." ></button>
```

As the title says, I need to insert a javascript code "Including the tags" inside my button onclick, so all this code has to be inside my button, because my script removes all js tags and scripts on the page, I tried to call an external js with no luck, but all js and tags inside my button onclick runs fine. Please note that scripts are not allowed on that page for security reasons, BUT, to extend the page's functions, I need to run this code, and the only way so far is inside my button, because I still can run scripts there.

I already tried to put single quotes in the script and everything, but I got stuck in the middle of the script, I need to reformat the script properly just like an ajax call onclick inside a button.

Comment: Can you elaborate more.

Comment: I mean to say elaborate clearly what you want to do. Plse include the code in question

Comment: Why don't you create a function smthing like onclick="fun();" and wrap up all code inside fun(){..}

Comment: Because the js in my button onclick event is the only way to run the code because jquery removes the tags and the js otherwise, so I got no choice, I tried everything.

Comment: Which way is not working for you?

Comment: function smthing like onclick="fun();" and wrap up all code inside fun(){..}

Comment: In fact, jquery removes all tags and js on the page where I need this code, but when I run the code inside a button onclick, it works ;), so I need to put all this code inside my button.

Comment: I'm afraid you can't do this.

Comment: Yes I can, I was able to run part of the code, but I'm stuck for the rest, and I can run any other code inside that button, but if I put the js code on the page, jquery removes it. But yes, I know it's a hard one ;-)

Comment: *because jquery removes all js tags and scripts on the page* - No it doesn't, unless you are writing JS to do that.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, and I'm in a very deep love with Jquery indeed, but inside my page's situation and structure, it does remove them, and the best way to avoid that and run js code on this page, is to run it inside my button.

Comment: @Marc This seems to be an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Could you give an example fiddle or snippet to show this, I don't see how what you mentioned is actually whats happening.

Comment: @Spencer, Yes, this a Y Problem, let's leave the X, because all this happen in a complex social network environment, please note also that on that page scripts are not allowed for security reasons, BUT, to extend the page's functions I need to run this code on the page, and the only way so far, is inside my button because I still can run scripts there, weird but maybe I just discovered something great.

Comment: @Marc You can place your JS all inside the `onclick` event, but it's bad practice to do so. Just make sure all your quotes inside are single quotes. But's it's clear the problem is X, which is what you need to solve.

Comment: @Spencer, Thanks and I know it's an ugly work around, I tried everything but I got stuck in the middle of the script, I actually need a real genius to reformat all the script properly inside that button, in fact, it's like an ajax call onclick inside a button.

Comment: *" but I got stuck in the middle of the script"*, could you explain what you mean?

Comment: This part doesn't work well inside my button, I think I need to reformat the syntax:=====     elgg.action(this.action, {
    data: $(this).serialize(),

    success: function(data){

Comment: But before I say anything, let me try your code first ;-)

Comment: I should also tell you that when I call all this code as " append" onlick, I can see all the code but NOT the tags in the source, because they are removed by Jquery, if I can find a way to keep the js tags when I append the code, my problem will be solved.

Comment: I will also try to chop the js scripts in parts, and also try jquery getScript and will tell you results.

Answer (score 1):

Normally doing this is considered bad practice. Although since you mentioned you cannot place `<script>`'s on the page (being removed for security reasons). Placing the code inside the `onclick` would look like so:

```
<button onclick=" 
$('#form_threaded_comment_<?php echo $unique_id;?>').submit(function(){
  $('#<?php echo $vars['resultId'] ?>').<?php echo $append_prepend?>('<?php echo $posting_icon?>');

    elgg.action(this.action, {
    data: $(this).serialize(),

    success: function(data){
      $('#form_threaded_comment_<?php echo $unique_id;?>_textarea').val('');
      $('#reply_form_<?php echo $vars['parent_guid']?>').remove();
      $('#<?php echo $vars['resultId'] ?>').<?php echo $append_prepend?>(data.output);
      $('#form_posting').remove();
    }
  });
  return false;
});">Test</button>
```

Here is a more simple example of displaying an alert:

```
<button onclick=" 
    function test() {
        alert('Hello World');
    }
    test();
">Hello World</button>
```

I would advise you to find out why script tags are being removed on a page and disable that, as this is the real problem which caused you to take this roundabout solution. As normally the above example would normally look something like this:

*HTML*

```
<button id="hello">Hello World</button>
```

*JS*

```
$("#hello").click(function(){
    alert("Hello World");
})
```